# The p-value of the test statistic in this problem is approximately equal to:

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

A survey claims that more than 8 out of 10 doctors recommend aspirin for their patients with
headaches. To test this claim, a random sample of 100 doctors’ results in 86 who indicate that they recommend aspirin.

A. 0.0521

B. 0.0802

C. 0.1231

D. 0.0721

E. 0.0668

So far I got:

Ho: P= 0.8

H1: P> 0.8

Z= (0.86-0.8)/0.4
= 1.50

If z= 1.50, cumulative probability is 0.9332

p-value= 2P(Z>zo)

= 2(1-0.9332)=0.1336

Correct answer seems to be 0.0668, which is half of 0.1336. Not sure where I went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{split}
H_0:\pi=.8\\
H_1:\pi>.8
\end{split}
$$

The test statistic is $z^*=\frac{.86-.8}{.4}$

So far so good

You are conducting a one-sided test, so you are only interested in the probability to the right of $z^*$. There is no need to multiply the area by two. The pvalue is is $P(Z>z^*)= 1-0.9332=0.0668$

There is some evidence against the null, that is, it is slightly unlikely that the you would see a sample proportion of .86 if the null hypothesis were true. Therefore it's possible that the true population proportion is greater than .8.